# No sound and bad resolution when Pi turned on before AVR

Tags: boot

I have my Raspberry Pi 400 hooked up through HDMI to an AVR  that is hooked up to a projector. When I turn the AVR on and then I turn the Pi, everything works.

When I do it the other way around I get picture (but no sound!) at 1280*720 resolution (I think), not the FullHD the projector supports.

I tried quite a few setting in `/boot/config.txt` but they seem to be making things worse (like no sound in all circumstances when I set `hdmi_drive=2`), so the only setting changed to default is `disable_overscan=1`.

Answer (score 1):

Force the display resolution using `raspi-config`.

From a terminal window use `sudo raspi-config`, select 'Display Options', then select 'Resolution', then select your required resolution.

Comment: When I do that, sound stops working in either case.